# How to get the elements in object array list

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4WgS.png)        I tried to get the value of an object[] but using foreach didn't work well.
        object[] contains a list of object[] how can I fetch the data

```
public void SaveBottonTable(string dimension)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    object[] routes_list = 
        (object[])json_serializer.DeserializeObject(dimension);
                GlobalConstant.holeconfiguration = routes_list;//list is referred in the image
    foreach(object hole in routes_list)
    {
        hole[0]//shows error
    }
}
```

[how to get the value of the first object[]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4WgS.png)

```
      https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8SG1.png
```

Comment: `object hole` represents single object.  when you do `hole[0]` you are trying to use single object as array of objects. That's why you are getting an error. You should do `var routes = hole as object[];` in foreach loop an then you can access individual objects from `routes` by doing `routes[0]`, `routes[1]` etc..

Comment: Posting the json would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Since each element is an array of strings you should convert each object to array and then index it.

```
foreach(object hole in routes_list)
{
   var elements = hole.ToArray();
//then you can access elements[0] and elements [1]
}
```

However, I think it would be better if the format was "Key":"Value"
Example: 
{
"object-ID":"1234123cfrewr",
"view" : "Cover",
.
.
.}

Be careful with Collection.Generics since you have a couple of Dictionaries there. They will need extra care.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `json` contains a dictionary. In that case I would deserialize it to the appropriate type `Dictionary<string, object>`. Then when looping through it you can either get the key using `hole.Key` or the value using `hole.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
object[] list = new object[]
{
    new object(),
    1,
    "ciao",
    new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    "pizza",
    new object[] { "ciao", "pizza" },
    new List<object>(){ 123, 456 }
};

foreach (ICollection collection in list.OfType<ICollection>())
{
    //Here you can work with every collection found in your list
}
```